# GRUB won't boot (no such device)

Tags: grub2

I have 4 hard disks (I am on Debian LiveCD now):

```
user@debian:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="EE2CE1122CE0D71D" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="AEB0F4D6B0F4A64D" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="WINYANCI" UUID="40BCF0AABCF09B9A" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdb5: LABEL="YAHSI" UUID="8efb4a53-f0fd-4e24-8217-1f27dff3d2b5" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc2: UUID="5c65c579-a385-4d89-b979-04c2c182d040" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdc3: UUID="c9a6ef89-c1b6-4827-8e3c-2ec39fcb1265" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc4: UUID="110b5c0c-cd0e-4284-99a5-61fe02c217ec" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc5: UUID="6ec4938a-71a7-4ea1-a9e6-9ed0c90c4a45" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc6: UUID="5D641D223A2A64B4" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdd2: LABEL="DEPO" UUID="02D8A6A9D8A69A85" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sdd5: LABEL="HUSUSI" UUID="E0949947949920D8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Debian wheezy 20140209-18:05" TYPE="iso9660" 
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
```

sdc is the new 1 TB hard disk, sda is where I have Windows 7 installed (and the old GRUB in MBR from my previous Debian installation) and sdb and sdd are just storage. Since I've bought a new shiny disk and I wanted to use GPT on my new disk and then partitioned it like this:

```
user@debian:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

Partition table scan:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  MBR: protective                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  BSD: not present                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  APM: not present                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  GPT: present                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

Command (? for help): p                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Disk /dev/sdc: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Logical sector size: 512 bytes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Disk identifier (GUID): 2758BB06-C7E7-451B-9C92-F1B278721BB6                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Partition table holds up to 128 entries                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Total free space is 3437 sectors (1.7 MiB)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   1            2048            6143   2.0 MiB     EF02                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   2            6144         8394751   4.0 GiB     8200                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   3         8394752        76754943   32.6 GiB    EF00                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   4        76754944       174409727   46.6 GiB    0700  
   5       174409728      1346283519   558.8 GiB   0700  
   6      1346283520      1953523711   289.6 GiB   0700
```

Then I went on to install Debian on sdc3 (which is /, sdc4 is /home). Installer asked me if it should install GRUB on MBR of sda. I said 'no' because there is a 2 MiB partition with `grub_bios` flag on sdc (since my old motherboard doesn't have UEFI) and I wanted to install GRUB there: 
[image: iTried]

Now, GRUB won't boot! Either it conflicts with the 'old' GRUB in sda's MBR (I thought, when I said GRUB to install on sdc there would be only one GRUB on sdc's GPT) or I failed to install GRUB correctly or installing it on sdc5 was completely stupid while I should have installed it on sdc1 or somewhere else on sdc... 
Any ideas how to solve this? 
[image: grubError]

**PS**: I have tried to reinstall GRUB reading this [tutorial](http://itsfoss.com/solve-error-partition-grub-rescue-ubuntu-linux/) but again the same error (this time I chose /dev/sdc as the location to install GRUB).

Answer (score 1):

you have not updated grub and grub tries to boot the `4ccef65b-...` device which doesn't exist.

You can choose between

- when the boot screen appears type <kbd>e</kbd> for edit. In the
   linux boot line change the `4cce...` with roo=/dev/sdc3 or whatever
   your root partition is. If your system is up, run update-grub.
- the hard way, is to boot from a rescue pen-drive, mount your root and 
  chroot (like explained in step 3 of your howto).

Useful links:

- [WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)
- [ReinstallingGrub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2)
- [Howot boot into Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135272/how-to-boot-into-windows-7-when-grub-is-installed-in-the-windows-partition)

Comment: Both ways didn't work. So as a final attempt I inserted the Win7 dvd and made a `/FixMbr`. Now GRUB boots. Though I have no idea how this worked.

Comment: According to [bootinfoscript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/), GRUB is installed on sda, sdc and sdd (http://paste.debian.net/hidden/e1e3a423/). I guess that's messed up. What should I do?

Comment: I inserted some links to the post, hope it will help.

Comment: @Infestor the paste.debian link is broken